# Having problems using Keras with symlinks

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory, symlink

I'm working on an image classification project where I need to maintain the structure of the original datasets, so I'm using symlinks (generated by `os.symlinks`) to reorganize all the folders and subfolders without having to copy all the files again. Since my computer is not up to the task, I'm using Google Colab to train a deep neural network thanks to models available in `Keras`. I'm having problems with the train, val and test generators created by `ImageDataGenerator`. When I call the `flow_from_directory` method, where I put `follow_links=True`, I get an output confirming that it finds images belonging to the binary classes I have to look for. But when I try to see some of the images in the batches, I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

What I'm doing wrong? Can somebody help, please?

Comment: Did you try to access the images via code without keras? I mean, trying to access the paths that image generatior recieves

Comment: Yes, before using Keras I've checked the symlinks by using os.readlink and the corresponding images are shown correctly.